# How to trigger crossbrowser FOCUS an a element with a neat outline?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

See the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/stefek99/9m5NZ/1/
Get the source: http://pastie.org/3654715

**Chrome 17**: just works.

**IE 9**: you need to click twice on "click"

**Firefox 11**: you need to give focus on some other element and then "click" works.

Why is that?
*(tried everything, have no clue)*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html  you should update your id tag to start with letters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `return false;` from your onclick handlers, otherwise browser may follow the link and decide to move focus elsewhere.

Watch out for "CSS resets" or similar which remove focus outlines. Add your own style:

```
:focus {outline: 2px solid blue;}
```

With those two modifications *it works for me*.

As for the "neatness" of the outline, that's up to the browser. WebKit has special `-webkit-focus-ring-color` for this. Gecko supports `-moz-outline-radius`. For cross-browser style you'll need to roll your own (try `border-image`).

Comment: `return false` - it was so easy! Thanks also for hint with styling.